# My class (container of pointers to another class) cannot seem to access the public constructor

Tags: c++, qt, pointers, containers

I am struggling to create a QList of pointers to objects of a self-made class, in this case *Node*. I have tried to use the same method as in the *Library* example of **An Introduction to Design Patterns in C++ with Qt**, Ezust and Ezust.

For some reason, the container class *NodeList* cannot access the constructor in the *Node* class and complains that it is private, even though it is public.

I have tried using the friend keyword in the definition of *Node*, but that did not work either. I cannot see where the problem is coming from, as I am referencing the pointers in exactly the same way as the working example from the textbook.

```
#ifndef NODE_H
#define NODE_H

#include <QString>
#include <QList>

class Node
{
public:
    Node() {}
    void setNodeLabel(QString label);
    QString getNodeLabel();
    Node(QString label);

private:
    QString nodeLabel;
};


class NodeList : public QList<Node*>
{
public:
    NodeList() {}
    ~NodeList();
    void addNode(Node*& node);
private:
    NodeList(const NodeList&);
    NodeList& operator=(const NodeList&);
};

#endif // NODE_H
```

The error I get when trying to compile this is as follows:

```
\qlist.h:106: error: 'struct QList<Node*>::Node' is private
 struct Node { void *v;
        ^

\node.h:25: error: within this context
 void addNode(Node*& node);
              ^
```

Comment: I dont fully understand the error, but maybe you should provide an empty default constructor

Comment: I'm wondering if there is any naming conflicts happening. Try changing the name of your class from "Node" to "MyNode" to see if it is generating the same error.

Comment: Avoid deriving from Qt template types, such as `QList`. This is one of the many reasons it's not recommended.

Comment: Thank you Francis. Renaming the class worked perfectly. I can't select your answer as the accepted answer though, as it's only a comment. Also, the answer from R Sahu was more detailed, so it would probably be more helpful to others. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NodeList` derives from `QList<Node*>`, which has a nested class named `Node`, which is in the `private` section of `QList`. When you use the unqualified type `Node` anywhere in `NodeList`, that name resolves to `QList<Node*>::Node`. Hence, you get that error.

Unless you intend to add more functionality to `NodeList`, you can use:

```
using NodeList = QList<Node*>;
```

and get rid of the class `NodeList`.

Comment: Thank you very much for the excellent answer I used Francis Cugler's suggestion to rename the class to MyNode, as I didn't realise that there was a bespoke Node class in QList. By your powers combined, you have solved my problem.